# ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender cant work on asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net

I would like to show a calender when i click the image button and the selected date will be display on the text box. I used ajaxtoolkit, but there is error show the not a known element(ToolkitScriptManager, CalendarExtender).

web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

my page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<table class="auto-style18">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style19">   
                        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>   <- error occur there(show not known element)                         
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiredDate" runat="server" Width="260px"></asp:TextBox>
                        &nbsp; </td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="Server" AlternateText="Click here to display calendar" Height="21px" ImageUrl="~/Images/calender.png" Width="26px" />                                    
                        <asp:CalendarExtender  ID="CalendarExtender1"  TargetControlID="txtExpiredDate" runat="server" />  <- error occur there(show not known element)                         
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Can you double check the tag prefix for your ToolkitScriptManager ? I see you've set it to "ajaxToolkit" in the Registration while it's set to "asp" in "asp:ToolKitScriptManager" in the page.

Comment: i change it to 
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager .....> but it does not work too...
When i run the page, it show me this error:
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Please make sure of the following:
1- You got AjaxControlToolkit.dll in the Assembly folder
2- you're using a recent version of the AjaxControlToolKit

Comment: Also make sure you're using the same tag prefix for the CalendarExtender

Comment: i solved this problem, but now another problem occur, when i click my image button, the calender cant apear..

Comment: It will be good if you post the answer you found so that it would be helpful to others. Also this seems to be a different issue, so please post it in a new question